# Angular 10 Google Maps Component, mover mapa o editar propiedades

Tags: javascript, angular, api, google-maps

Estoy usando el componente nuevo que existe de Google Maps para angular 10 sobre la api de google maps JS de Google. https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps

He logrado crear este mapa y marcar un centro al inicio, tras esto he logrado crear un marker, lo que quiero es que tras haber obtenido la localización el mapa se mueve hasta este nuevo punto. He intentado varias cosas pero no logro conseguir nada. Este es mi html por el momento:

```html
 <google-map width=100% height=300px id="googleMap">
     <map-marker *ngFor="let markerPosition of markerPositions" [position]="markerPosition" [options]="markerOptions"> 
     </map-marker>
 </google-map>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las opciones del mapa las tengo añadidas al principio de mi archivo ts:

```js
markerOptions: google.maps.MarkerOptions = { draggable: false };
  markerPositions: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [];

  mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 37.779712700000005, lng: -3.7943255999999996 },
    zoom : 16,
    tilt: 45,
  // display: google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
 
  mapTypeControl: false,
  // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
  disableDefaultUI: true
 }
```

Como he dicho tengo un centro por defecto que nada tiene que ver con la localización real, entonces usando Capacitor Geolocation obtengo la ubicación real, el problema es que quiero que este haga un desplazamiento como he comentado antes.

Esto es lo que intento hacer:

```js
let posicion = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
let LatLng = { lat: posicion.coords.latitude, lng: posicion.coords.longitude}
this.addMarkerMap(LatLng)
    
//NO SE SI ESTE METODO SET CENTER DEBERIA DE APLICARSELO A MI MAPA YA CREADO, PERO NO CONSIGO OBTENER EL MAPA YA CREADO
google.maps.Map.prototype.setCenter(latLng)

// ESTABA INTENTANDO OBTENER EL MAPA DE ESTA FORMA PERO NO CONSIGO OBTENER ESE OBJETO MAPA PARA PODERLE CAMBIAR LA PROPIEDAD O USAR "PAINTO" PARA MOVERME 
this.mapG = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") as HTMLElement);
```